# Oracle TABLE TYPE

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I have a scenario where I was using global objects, but I have been informed that some database changes means I can no longer do that. So I am passing an anonymous procedure through a Java prepared statement.

I have passed in the parameter data as an xml which I have converted to a local type.

```
DECLARE
    xmlData XMLTYPE := ?
    TYPE o_myData IS RECORD (my_num NUMBER);
    TYPE t_myData IS TABLE OF o_myData INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    myData t_myData;
BEGIN
    --xmlData conversion

    SELECT * FROM TABLE(t_myData) --does not work because the type is local
```

Are there any other options?

Comment: what is going in your t_mydata array?

Comment: @Boneist the xmlData conversion fills it with numbers from the xml.

Comment: Can't you use `XMLTABLE` on the XML itself to pull out the data into a SQL statement?